# Does the badge requirements make sense for a security site?

Tags: discussion, badges

Considering that this is a lot more niche and has a lot less users than stackoverflow should we reduce some of the requirements for badges e.g. Asked a question with 10,000 views to encourage more people to contribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one was answered over on meta.SO **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69689/154443)** - @dmckee's answer sums up what I think is the main problem.

Another one is just around identifying what levels to set, and when.

Comment: alsop Makes sense.